# Aligning labels in array in C# to form a grid

Tags: c#, label, picturebox

I have created an array of black labels and have displayed them on a picture box. Unfortunately, I am not able to line them up directly at each intersection of the black lines. How can I do this?

```
InitializeComponent();

        int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;

        int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

        // create 361 labels, set their properties
        for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
        {
            board[i] = new Label();
            board[i].Parent = pictureBox1;
            board[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            board[i].Name = "label" + i;
            board[i].Text = "0";
            board[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
            //set size of labels
            board[i].Size = new Size(31,31);

        }


        // set the position of the label
        foreach (Label i in board)
        {
            //set distance between labels
            if (x >= 1024)
            {
                x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
                y += 52;
            }

            else
            {
                x += 52;
            }


            this.Controls.Add(i);
            i.BringToFront();
            i.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i have understand your question, and saw your code.

you are creating labels at same 
`Location(x,y)` where `x = 100` and `y = 0`

in the next loop

```
    foreach (Label i in board)
    {
        if (x >= 1024)
        {
            x = 0;
            y += i.Height + 55;
        }

        else if (y >= 1024)
        {
            y = 0;
            x += i.Width + 55;
        }
    }
```

None of your condition will become true, because your x = 100 and y = 0
so location will remain same and all labels will be at same location

if you want to display a chess grid see this method
[Chess Grid in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733310/creating-a-chess-board-using-windows-forms)

if you want to display labels on intersection of lines then lets modify your Code

```
        x = PictureBox1.Location.X + 55;
        y = pictureBox1.Location.Y + 55;
        for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
            {
                board[i] = new Label();
                board[i].Parent = pictureBox1;
                board[i].Location = new Point(x,y); 
                board[i].Name = "label" + i;    
                board[i].Text = "0";
                board[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
                board[i].Size = new Size(55,55); //Define size of label according to your choice 
                if(x >= 1024)
                {
                  x = PictureBox1.Location.X + 55; //Start position
                  y += 55;                    // Step to next line
                }
                else
                  x += 55;                   //jump to next horizontal box
            }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: So what should I set x and y to? I cannot simply leave it declared without a value or declare a value within any loop.

Comment: Apart by 55 on each side

Comment: I want to display them as pieces on each intersection of the lines

Comment: How Can I properly line these up?

Comment: you have to manage it by defining your bounds. i dont know what they are at your side.

Change the size of your labels. as i used it as 10 x 10
change the value of jump, as i used it as 55.
adjust it according to your need bro.

i just could give you the hints and help you to identify your problem.
if i could help you then you can mark it as answer, the rest is the logic at your side.

but here is a suggestion: if you are planning to develop a chess game then this logic is hard to implement. 
check that link i have already given to you. but if you are doing something else then go with it

Comment: Not planning on a chess game but my main concern here is that they are not in 19 x 19 rows so I can't space them out equally... Would it be easier to create a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set a boundary for the labels. Look at the picture above. I don't want them going outside the image.

Comment: my pleasure if i could help you :)