# Matrix of photos

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a code that injects an image into my project through resources  `Image foodWorld = Resources.orange` and I want to make a matrix out of this photo, so it can look like this:

[image: Matrix]

I have this code but I don't know how to draw the matrix. Also, I don't know if this is the right way to draw it or not:

```
this.Width = 400;
this.Height = 300;

Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);

for(int i = 0; i < this.Height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < this.Width; j ++)
    {
        //fill the matrix
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when executed? What is your "fill the Matrix" Code? Keep in mind that you need to calculate the size of each Icon, or else it will get planted inside of each other

Comment: What is `this`? Are there 120,000 elements or 150 like the picture you attached suggests? What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: Any idea how can I do that? Generally, how can I do a matrix of photos like that one

Comment: Use this: `using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b) { ..yourloops.}` In the code calculate the positions&size and both a destination rectangle and the source rectangle. Then write `g.DrawImage(yourorangebmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphisUnit.Pixels);` Done. Note that your loops atm goes 300x400 times. You will want to correct that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Chess Board using Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733310/creating-a-chess-board-using-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with WinForms, but in WPF, I'd do it this way:

```
var columns = 15;
var rows = 10;

var imageWidth = 32;
var imageHeight = 32;

var grid = new Grid();
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        //Get the image in your project; I'm not sure how this is done in WinForms
        var b = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight);

        //Display it
        var pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Image = b;

        //Set the position
        Grid.SetColumn(j, pictureBox);
        Grid.SetRow(i, pictureBox);

        //Insert into the "matrix"
        grid.Children.Add(pictureBox);
    }
}
```

For moving Pacman, repeat the above, but for only one image. Store a reference to the current position and when certain keys are pressed,

- Animate it's margin until it appears to be in an adjacent cell (for instance, if each cell is 16 pixels wide and pacman should be in the center of any given cell, animate the right margin by 16 pixels to get it into the cell on the right and so forth).
- Once it has moved to another cell, set the new row and column based on the direction in which it last moved.
- If there is a fruit at the new position, get the fruit at that position and remove it from the `Grid`. You can get it by using `myGrid.Children[currentRow * totalColumns + currentColumn]` assuming `currentRow` and `currentColumn` are both zero-based.
- Repeat for each cell it must move to.

This does mean the matrix will have a fixed size, but in WPF, there is a `Viewbox`, which is convenient for these types of scenarios. Also, set the z-index of pacman to be greater than the fruits so it's always on top.

Comment: in WPF it would have been ItemsControl bound to some collection, without any code-behind

Comment: I agree that that is the ideal approach; however, OP is not using WPF so presenting an example that uses data binding isn't very useful here.

Comment: WPF is not useful here at all then

Comment: My example is meant to be used with WinForms based on what the OP already knows. I never claimed this example was WPF-based, which should be obvious considering WPF doesn't have a `PictureBox`. Based on my experience with WPF, I filled in the gaps for the purposes of providing a potential solution for WinForms.